# @echo off command doesn't display as coded initally

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i've recently got to .batch file coding and when i try a code like

```
@echo off
echo Hello World!
pause
```

It says:

```
C:\Users\David Rijo\Desktop>´╗┐@echo off
'´╗┐@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\David Rijo\Desktop>echo Hello World!
Hello World!

C:\Users\David Rijo\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no extra characters before the `@echo`?

Comment: 100% and that's the problem i write @echo and in cmd it shows those wierd signs

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25423160/2861476) could help

Comment: Do **not** use Notepad++ editor to write Batch files (unless you know the related problems to do so)...